# Image is not rendering DOM pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

**image is not rendering DOM pdf, here is my code**

```php
$baseurl = Config::get('app.baseurl');
$logoImagepath = $baseurl . '/assets/images/logo.png';

$invoicePDF = Config::get('settings.invoice');
$invoicePDF = str_replace('#imagepath#', $logoImagepath, $invoicePDF);

$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.order_detail', compact('invoicePDF'))
          ->save($saveInvoicePdfPath);
```

HTML get from config, all HTML is rendered properly but image is not showing in PDF.

if I print HTML code, image render successfully.

please suggest me solution.

Comment: Where is `PDF::loadview` coming from? are you using a package?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check **$isRemoteEnabled = true;** in your dompdf opltions settings.